# Standard deviation without min and max figures in excel (data represents in B1:S1)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, standard-deviation

Have a data in columns B1:S1 and have to find standard deviation without min and max figures.

The best and correct formula for my case which I found in internet was:

**STDEV(LARGE($A$1:$A$10,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&COUNT($A$1:$A$10)-1))))** - but that works if only you have data in **A1:A10**.

How can we implement this for a data in column **B1:S1** ?

Comment: Do you have sample data with expected outcome?

Comment: Hi @Zaur can you clarify `" have to find standard deviation without min and max figures"` - for sd you only need the series of data - I dont understand the significance of min and max in your problem - thanks for any clarification

Comment: @Zaur, please visualize this inside your OP. See [ask] a question with an [mcve] and edit accordingly. Not everyone does read comments below a post.

Comment: @JohnnieL think about it like standard deviation without outliers. In my calculation I should exclude the min and max figures in 18 month cash inflows

Comment: @JvdV yes. I have sample data of 18 month. First 2 month of which is 0

Comment: @Zaur - Why can you not replace a1:a10 with b1:s1? Do you mean that you have multiple columns of data? Are you treating `a1 .... s18` as *different* data sets or a single data set? i.e. you want the stdev.s treating `a1..s18` as your single input data set?

Comment: @JohnnieL suppose there are  100 customers with 18 month data and you should show their standard deviations in a column each customer name below another. Besides I have another data which should be represent in columns in front of each customer

Comment: @JohnnieL the formula above won't work if I replace A1:A10 with B1:S1 because Row(indirect) part of the formula won't work wich Columns. Syntax like Column(Indirect... also won't work in this case.

Comment: i'm somewhat confused, what error do you get with `STDEV(LARGE(b1:S1,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&COUNT(B1:S1)-1)))) `? that works just fine for me or adjusted to `STDEV(LARGE(C3:T3,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&COUNT(c3:t3)-1))))` - that works just fine for me

Comment: see below - only way to post an image

Answer (score 1):

```
=STDEV(LARGE(B1:S1,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&COUNT(B1:S1)-1))))
```

[image]

Comment: thx a lot. I checked it again and it works fine this time. I guess there was a mistake with my date which led to incorrect results. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is

```
=STDEV(IF((B1:S1>MIN(B1:S1))*(B1:S1<MAX(B1:S1)),B1:S1))
```

This may give a different result from the original formula in the case when the maximum and/or minimum value is repeated because it would remove more than two values from the range.

[image]

Comment: thx for answer. But this formula is not suitable for my case as I should not consider double min and max figures. So the formula above it works fine.

Comment: OK. Still worth posting I think as some people may need to trim their data like this.